# Two Free to Move Opposite Charges vs. Fixing One in Place: Do they still spiral?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, charge

[Assumption: Classical Electromagnetism, Special Relativity]

Consider the following two cases in (x, y)-coordinate system:

1. Positively charged particle A is placed at the origin of a coordinate system. Negatively charged particle B is placed at coordinate (1, 0) with an initial velocity in +y direction such that the electrostatic attraction between the two charged particles would make particle B orbit in a circle; analogous to the two-body problem in classical mechanics. **Particles A and B are free to move after the initial set up.**
2. Everything is set up as in 1., however in this case only negatively charged particle B is free to move, and **positively charged particle A is fixed at the origin.**

---

Two versions of time evolution (as far as I can see):

- In both cases 1. and 2. negatively charged particles B emit EM waves and spiral down to particle A.

In 1st case particle A is free to move so it's emitting EM waves and spiraling at the same time as particle B. In 2nd case all I can see influencing particle B  is an electric field created by particle A, and because particle A is fixed in place (at the origin), then the electric field produced by particle A is fixed at all points in space. Since particle B is spiraling it has to feel an additional force to the one caused by an electric field from particle A at every point on the spiraling trajectory.

***Question***: What is the source of this additional force that particle B feels? Is particle B influencing itself and how exactly does that work and when does it apply? (All I can see is particle A influencing particle B and particle B influencing itself, and influence of particle A is completely accounted for, because the particle is fixed and so is its electric field.)

- Only in the 1st case does negatively charged particle B emit EM waves and spiral down to particle A. In 2nd case particle B moves around the origin in a circle.

Moving around in a circle is consistent with the fixed electric field produced by particle A. However, charged particle B should still be emitting EM waves.

***Question***: If particle B is emitting EM waves and those waves carry energy from the system, then where does that energy come from? That same particle isn't spiraling; in other words, it isn't getting closer to particle A and therefore it isn't using up potential energy of the system.

---

I am pretty sure that this isn't really a paradox. This is most likely a result of misconceptions I have about the EM theory. Please help me understand who is influencing what and how that results in true motion of particles in the two systems described above.